# Getting computed properties with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the computed properties of an element using JavaScript. Is it even possible? I have seen Chrome showing computed properties of elements like `li` and `a`. I just thought I could get the same using JavaScript. Whenever I tried, it's showing undefined.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "computed properties"?

Comment: no, my properties are not defined, actually. is there a way to retrive undefined properties. these are the properties calculated by the browser. example - if i give image width as 80%, the Javascript should return size in pixels according to the user's viewport size.

Comment: @microman Do you mean the computed *dimensions*?

Comment: @microman pertaining your example, width is always returned in pixels not percent and hence a computed value already!

Comment: but when i tried the same with an li element, it returned undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`:

```
var width = document.getElementById('elementId').offsetWidth;
```

More Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements

You may also want to look at this: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html

**Edit**:

You may want to consider: `window.getComputedStyle(element)` as well. There are problems relating to subpixel rendering with offsetX.

More info here: http://vadikom.com/dailies/offsetwidth-offsetheight-useless-in-ie9-firefox4/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is highly suggested.

usage:

html:

```
<img src="img_src.png" id="img1" />
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    alert('width: ' + $('#img1').width());
    alert('height: ' + $('#img1').height());
    alert('left offset: ' + $('#img1').offset().left);
    alert('top offset: ' + $('#img1').offset().top);
});
</script>
```

OR

pure javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var img = document.getElementById('img1');
    alert('width: ' + img.width);
    alert('height: ' + img.height);
}
</script>
```

hope that helps

Comment: anything possible with jQuery is possible with JavaScript as well, huh? please suggest a JavaScript way as I'm not planning to implement jQuery.

Comment: Use .getComputedStyle? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle

Comment: @microman You do not need to implement jQuery yourself. It's already there for you to use.

Comment: No, i'm not plannig to implement any of the jQuery related stuffs. At around 250 kb, jQuery is overkill for my website.

Comment: @microman see my comment above, or otherwise you can also, have a look at Zepto (~5-10k): http://zeptojs.com/#css

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can access css props via .css()

http://api.jquery.com/css/

> The .css() method is a convenient way to get a style property from the first matched element, especially in light of the different ways browsers access most of those properties (the getComputedStyle() method in standards-based browsers versus the currentStyle and runtimeStyle properties in Internet Explorer) and the different terms browsers use for certain properties.